# How to use the assumption that a vector field is curl-free in a "convex" region,

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, physics, vector-analysis, mathematical-physics

I don't seem to need this assumption in one of my proofs, but the problem statement gives it, so I think I had better try to use it.

Does a convex region imply that it is simply connected (but that the converse need not be true)?

And then a curl-free vector field in a convex, simply connected region, must be conservative -- and so it is a gradient vector field.

I.e., Perhaps I needed to know that the region was simply connected before claiming the vector field is conservative -- the curl-free assumption alone does not give enough information.  What do you think?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Yes, convex implies simply-connected. In fact, convex implies contractible: choose a point $x_0$ in the set. For any other point $x$, define $h(t,x) = (1 - t)x + tx_0$. $h$ is a contraction of the set to a point. Any closed curve in the set also contracts to a point under $h$, so the set is simply-connected.
- No, the converse is not necessarily true: consider a half-circle, for example.
- And yes, in general you need to know that the domain is simply-connected before you can prove that the integral around closed loops is $0$ when a derivative is $0$. Otherwise you can pick up a constant factor when you circle around a singularity. This holds no matter what type of derivative it is.

Comment: Ok, got it -- thanks so much @PaulSinclair :-)  I actually posted my proof in full detail in a new question on MSE, if you want to look at it and comment on it :-)  Reviewing my proof and the problem statement, I believe that the question has given one too many assumptions -- namely that divF=0.  (This would make applying the Divergence theorem a little silly.)  Thanks,